# Java Script array.indexOf is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That's was surprise, but simple function array.IndexOf is not working.

```
$scope.nextProduct = function (pos, item) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0: product = $scope.Menu[0].Breakfast
            break
        case 1: product = $scope.Menu[0].Lunch
            break
        case 2: product = $scope.Menu[0].BeforTraining
            break
        case 3: product = $scope.Menu[0].AfterTraining
            break
        case 4: product = $scope.Menu[0].Dinner
            break
        default: product = $scope.Menu[0].Breakfast
            break
    }
    var index = product.indexOf(item.Name);
    product[index - 1].IsSelect = false;
    product[index + 1].IsSelected = true;
}
```

indexOf return -1 but I'm completely sure that the item exist in array. What can be wrong here?[image]

Comment: No, the object doesn't exist: an object whose "name" is the same as item.Name exists, that's very different.

Comment: Well, but item.Name it's just string, isn't it?

Comment: Your searching an array of objects for a string, how does it know you want to match the .Name property?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this in the console? If you set a breakpoint on line 211. You can then execute JS in the console. This will be the quickest way to debug your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this expression you are searching for a string in object array.

```
product.indexOf(item.Name);
```

Instead you should run:

```
var res = product.filter(function(elem){
    return elem.Name == someValue
})
```

this returns array matching your value

Comment: `map` would be more suitable as OP needs the index. For example: `var index = product.map(function(p) { return p.Name; }).indexOf(item.Name);`

Comment: @OscarBarrett, yes, that's exactly what I need. Please add comment as answer.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak, yes, your solution is working but that's not what I need.

Comment: @andrey.shedko yep I see

Comment: @andrey.shedko I would have added my comment as an answer, however this question has been marked as a duplicate and is therefore locked.